# How to move more objects in a coordinated manner with the particle system

Tags: animation, particles, physics, bezier-curves

Hello to every blender user.

I'm trying to configure the particle system because I want that it generates a certain number of cars that should follow a curve. I have different types of cars. Here's how I built the cars. Each car has 4 wheels that run continuously. I put the car's origin in the center of the car body and I have parented an empty object to it. Then I also parented the 4 wheels with the empty object.

[image: 1]

Finally, to make the wheels spin I created a driver, configured as follows:

1. type = scripted expression
2. expr = -var
3. object = Empty_car_citrus
4. type = x location
5. space = world space

[image: 2]

I come to the point. I want to configure the particle system so that it can make the car body and the 4 wheels walk together (not disorderly). And I do not know how to do it. On the particle system configuration, I can choose between object and group. I tried to give to it the the car body as an object and the car is moved correctly. Also a single wheel moves correctly. But I do not know how to do if I want to move the car body and the 4 wheels together, at the same time. I also tried to add the wheels and the body inside a group and then I gave the group name to the particle system, but it does not work. The parts of the car move messy. This is because the car is not a single object, but is made up of 6 objects. The car body, the 4 wheels and the empty object. It would be easier if I could join the wheels with the car body, but I can not, because then the wheels do not turn anymore...I have also another problem,the cars cross the floor...

[image: 3]

Comment: Try applying the scale, so they all have a scale of 1.0 - Ctrl-A->Scale. To align the car to the floor, move the object origin to the bottom of the car.

Comment: I have applied the scale to each component of the car,like the wheels and at the empty object,but it did not work. Infact I don't know which object should I choose on the render tab of the particles configuration...if I choose the car body,the wheels haven't been attached...